# Measured Earth local gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, resource-recommendations, earth, measurements, data

I am looking for measured data of the local gravity on Earth. I know this website (https://www.ptb.de/cartoweb3/SISproject.php). The idea is nice but it looks a bit old and I would like to have an alternative source.

Comment: You might want to look at [GRACE](http://www2.csr.utexas.edu/grace/): there's a lot of available data from it which might be a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The best open-source source on Earth's gravity is EGM 08 (Earth Gravitational Model 2008):

http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm2008/

Of course, EGM08 defines an abstract equi-potential surface (as a spherical harmonics expansion), so it doesn't have anything to do with force; however, it also comes with gravitational anomalies (which are deviations in the magnitude of the acceleration) and defections from vertical.